# how to handle JSON content with additional text into it

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a `JSON` string like below and it can have multiple objects separated with commas or sometimes it can have only one object.The children `Property` can have values or can be [] (`NULL`).

How could I read all name `Property` values from this kind of string?

This structure value is dynamic. 
`JObject.Parse()` is throwing an exception that additional text exist while parsing.

```
[
   {
      "name": "AML Policy",
      "children": [
         {
            "name": "Test",
            "children": [
               {
                  "name": "Test123",
                  "children": []
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name": "AML Policy2",
      "children": []
   }
]
```

Comment: Please, show your attempt to parse the data

Comment: Have you tried JArray.Parse(obj)?

Comment: This is a tree. Parse it as such.

Comment: Does it have the same structure everywhere? I mean a member `name` and a member `children` that is an array containing the same structure again ?

Comment: Where is that additional text ?

Comment: What does "additional text" mean here? This is valid JSON.

Comment: Note that if you use `JObject.Parse`, it is expected that the JSON contains an object at the root level. This JSON does not, it contains a list, so JObject.Parse will not be able to parse this JSON. You should instead use JArray.Parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<RootObject> children { get; set; }
}
```

Method to read all names recursively

```
public static void PushNamesToList(List<string> names, List<RootObject> rootObject)
{
    foreach (var row in rootObject)
    {
        names.Add(row.name);
        if (row.children.Count > 0) PushNamesToList(names, row.children);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);

var lstNames = new List<string>();
PushNamesToList(lstNames, result);

foreach(var item in lstNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Dont bother with a List when you dont have too. Also in C#, properties are in PascalCase. [Check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450038/1248177).

Comment: Hi
 this really helps a lot.
How can i get these names as per every json object, something like below:
List<string> Names = AML Policy / Test/Test123  and AML Policy 1

Comment: glad it worked for you @Neelam. i will update the post with your requirement

Comment: I am trying to change PrintNames method as per my requirement to get Names in above format( AML Policy / Test/Test123) , but it doesn't allow me to iterate on RootObject

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com, I have to go for `List` as I am checking the count during recursion

Comment: I should admire your quick response. Thank you for all the support.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of structure is a tree. You have to deserialize your json as such.

You can do it in one line:

```
var tests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Test>>(json);
```

With the class `Test` being:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Test> Children { get; set; }
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YS5Df3)

Full program:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public IEnumerable<Test> Children {get;set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"[
   {
      ""name"": ""AML Policy"",
      ""children"": [
         {
            ""name"": ""Test"",
            ""children"": [
               {
                  ""name"": ""Test123"",
                  ""children"": []
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      ""name"": ""AML Policy2"",
      ""children"": []
   }
]";

        var tests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Test>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(tests.Last().Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: as per OP, he wants the names recursively to `List`

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla as this point this a whole other question for an OP who dont even post a [MCVE]. I pass.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string json = @"[{
                'name': 'AML Policy',
                'children': [{
                     'name': 'Test',
                     'children': [{
                          'name': 'Test123',
                          'children': []
                           }]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    'name': 'AML Policy2',
                    'children': []
                }]";
       var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Input>>(json);
       Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
}

public class Input
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Input> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Dont bother with a List when you dont have too. Also in C#, properties are in PascalCase. [Check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450038/1248177).